# HTTP call in windows shell script

Tags: shell, windows-shell

I want to create a windows shell script to send an http request and get response, for example call http://google.com and get the response headers, etc. How can I do this job?

Answer (score 0):

Use VBScript (or JScript) and the Microsoft.XmlHttp object.

```
CreateObject("Microsoft.XmlHttp")
```

Use the GetAllResponseHeaders method on the result.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms535874(v=vs.85).aspx

If it needs to be shell script that have your shell echo the VBScript into a .vbs file and use cshell to execute it.

Comment: You mean it isn't possible by pure shell scripting?

Comment: @ehsandotnet - You could always use PowerShell but that's no different when you consider the amount of abstraction. So either use PowerShell or VBScript or JScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using PowerShell, try this:

```
$url = "http://google.com"
[net.httpWebRequest] $request = [net.webRequest]::create($url)
[net.httpWebResponse] $response = $request.getResponse()
$responseStream = $response.getResponseStream()
$sr = new-object IO.StreamReader($responseStream)
$result = $sr.ReadToEnd()
$result
```

That will pull the html portion of the webpage.

Comment: Does it have any requirements to run in other windows machines?

Comment: It requires .Net. I think it goes back to version 1.1, although the functionality might be different for older versions. More info here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx